Can you be found guilty of a crime even if it's not you who is on trial?
If you are pressing charges against someone for assault, and during the trial against them, it is found that you are guilty of trying to kidnap their child and that's why they attacked you, could you be charged even though you weren't the defendant of the trial? What would happen in this situation?

Cases can only be joined as a pre-trial motion, and only when the defendants are accused of related crimes. For instance, two people on trial for assaulting each other could not be joined, two people accused of assaulting a third could be.

If you have committed a crime you can be charged unless the statute of limitations or any other time limits in your state have run out.

You can't be charged in the same case, which is what I think that the question is really asking.

@ohwilleke that was addressed in comments.

@ohwilleke Obviously it's not the same case, since they're completely different cromes and charges. They're not asking about a situation where someone else becomes the suspect in the original crime.

You would be charged later, independently, if the defendant in an assault case makes a believable claim that they beat you up because you committed a serious crime.

To answer this.

Yes you can be charged with information that is discovered during the course of someone else's trial (unless you were granted immunity for testifying or something).

However being "charged" is not the same thing as "convicted". It is innocent until proven guilty or poor in this country. You will get your own trial with the same judge or a different judge. Your own defense lawyer, etc...

The person who assaulted you would probably walk away a free person. I don't think any jury or judges that would convict someone for protecting their child from a kidnapper. And I don't know of any prosecutors who want to be famous for sending Dave to jail for protecting his kid from a kidnapper.



Protecting your child falls under self defense, so it would likely be a valid defense to the assault charge.

Your answer would be improved if you omitted the "or poor" editorializing. It may be de facto true, but this isn't the place for it.
